# F# FSI fsi.AddPrinter: add link to output

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, f#-interactive, ionide

I'm using VS Code with the ionide plugin.
I would like add Hyperlink to the output of a fsi.AddPrinter function.
Something like this Code:

```
fsi.AddPrinter (fun (wi:WorkItem) -> 
    wi.Id 
    |> sprintf "http://server:port/path/%i"
    |> sprintf "[link](%s)" 
)
```

The created otput is not *clickable*, meaning the link is displayed but i can not click it. 
Some error mssages do produce links, that can be (Ctrl-)clicked.

A link like this works:

- http://aka.ms/witclientom

A link like

- http://server:port/path/path/path/path/
- http://server/path/path/path/path

does not work.

Is there some way to use somthing like markdown to specify a link in the output?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that I have to add the Domain to the link:
This link works:

http://server.company.com:port/path/path/path/path/